# Django - use template tag and 'with'?

Tags: django

I have a custom template tag:

```
def uploads_for_user(user):
    uploads = Uploads.objects.filter(uploaded_by=user, problem_upload=False)
    num_uploads = uploads.count()
    return num_uploads
```

and I'd like to do something like this, so I can pluralize properly:

```
{% with uploads_for_user leader as upload_count %}
    {{ upload_count }} upload{{ upload_count|pluralize }}
{% endwith %}
```

However, `uploads_for_user leader` doesn't work in this context, because the 'with' tag expects a single value - Django returns:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /upload/
u'with' expected format is 'value as name'
```

Any idea how I can get round this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could turn it into a filter:

```
{% with user|uploads_for as upload_count %}
```

Comment: Django 1.5+ lets you do this more succinctly.
    {% with upload_count=user|uploads_for %}

[django with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Answer (score 14):

While a filter would still work, the current answer to this question would be to use [assignment tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags), introduced in Django 1.4.

So the solution would be very similar to your original attempt:

```
{% uploads_for_user leader as upload_count %}
{{ upload_count }} upload{{ upload_count|pluralize }}
```

**Update**: As per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) assignment tags are deprecated since Django 1.9 (simple_tag can now store results in a template variable and should be used instead)

Comment: assignment tags deprecated since 1.9 - edited the answer

Answer (score 11):

In Django 1.9 django.template.Library.assignment_tag() is depricated:
simple_tag can now store results in a template variable and should be used instead.

So, now [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag) we can use like a:

> It’s possible to store the tag results in a template variable rather
>   than directly outputting it. This is done by using the as argument
>   followed by the variable name. Doing so enables you to output the
>   content yourself where you see fit:

```
{% get_current_time "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p" as the_time %}
<p>The time is {{ the_time }}.</p>
```